# Tensorflow tf.matmul example is incorrect?

Tags: python, matrix, tensorflow

I read the official document for [tf.matmul](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matmul) 
and I understand the first example.
It is a simple [2,3] x [3,2] operation:

```
a = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], shape=[2, 3])

b = tf.constant([7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], shape=[3, 2])

c = tf.matmul(a, b) => [[58 64]
                    [139 154]]
```

However, the second example seems very strange :

```
a = tf.constant(np.arange(1, 13, dtype=np.int32),
            shape=[2, 2, 3])

b = tf.constant(np.arange(13, 25, dtype=np.int32),
            shape=[2, 3, 2])

c = tf.matmul(a, b) => [[[ 94 100]
                     [229 244]],
                    [[508 532]
                     [697 730]]]
```

Why the matrix with shape [2,2,3] is allowed to multiply with [2,3,2] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the same page (https://web.archive.org/web/20170223153510/https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matmul):

> Returns:
>       A `Tensor` of the same type as `a` and `b` where each inner-most matrix is
>       the product of the corresponding matrices in `a` and `b`, e.g. if all
>       transpose or adjoint attributes are `False`:
>       `output`[..., i, j] = sum_k (`a`[..., i, k] * `b`[..., k, j]),
>       for all indices i, j.

Hence a matrix with shape [2,2,3] is allowed to multiply with [2,3,2].

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I am not good at matrix math, I didn't get the meaning of "inner-most matrix" in the above document...

Comment: @rainfer If a tensor has shaped  [a,b,c], its innermost matrix has shape  [b,c]

Comment: I got it. I just do the test with matrix [2,3,4,5] and [2,3,5,4] and it works. However, does it means that the tf.matmul is different from numpy's matrix multiply ?

Comment: @rainfer Looks similar https://web.archive.org/web/20170223160336/https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html "If either argument is N-D, N > 2, it is treated as a stack of matrices residing in the last two indexes and broadcast accordingly." (I'm not sure if TensorFlow does broadcast in that case though)

Comment: I'm sorry. I was confused by normal numpy's  a * b operation. Thank you so much.